# Do I have to be careful about DNS I'm using?

Tags: network, dns

There's some website which I can't have access to and they return 403 error to me. On the other hand, there are some DNS servers, where if I use them, I can have access to those websites!

Does using these unknown DNS servers cause any security risks for me? Is there any way for the owner of DNS to use my computer or my IP address... or any malicious act or cyber attack?

Comment: "A sketchy DNS server gives me access to controlled websites. Should I be concerned that they might do something to me?" -- yes ...

Comment: "unknown DNS server" - define "unknown"? What does that mean? You know about them. How do they grant you access? What do they actually do?

Comment: Without knowing what these servers are doing, it will be difficult to determine what the risks are. However, at the very least, all of your DNS queries will be known to them (and your IP, but that's not a big threat). They could also redirect all your traffic to their servers and monitor or intercept your traffic (if TLS allows it).

Comment: @schroeder These DNS servers are provided by some companies, but I don't know! can I trust them or not!? I know a little about network and I can guess (as you do too) what they might do to bypass limits on those websites but I'm not sure!

Comment: @schroeder Think of these DNS servers as 1.1.1.1 or 1.0.0.1 DNS server, with a difference, that you don't know who's the owner!

Comment: Then, for the generic case, the duplicate I've linked is your answer.